# Is an unfinished bridge a running joke in the original series cast Star Trek movies?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-movies

Upon re-watching a couple of the Star Trek movies which featured the original series cast, I noticed that in both *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*, and *Star Trek: The Final Frontier*, Kirk first arrives on the Enterprise bridge to find it unfinished, full of workers struggling noisily to complete their tasks.

Because this occurs more than once, I am wondering if it was a running joke by the writers - when Kirk urgently needs to get under way, his ship (or more specifically his bridge) is in shambles.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a running joke as much as [it is a trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnfinishedUntestedUsedAnyway).

Comment: Don't forget the gag in Generations where everything is being installed next Tuesday.

Comment: @DavidW I see the trope aspect - drama/tension arising from deploying something untested out of desperation. What struck me was how similar the scenes were in the movies I mentioned in the noise/chaos/frenzy. On the matter of tropes, Wrath of Khan fit too because of the "untested" rookie crew, and perhaps also Search for Spock because Scotty's automation wasn't meant to handle a combat scenario. Then there's The Voyage Home aboard a rickety Bird of Prey, and (as Valorum points out), all those things to be installed/crew to arrive on Tuesday in Generations.